# SVG image not show when set display none

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I code a web app, in this have some images tag and I set it display to none.  Like example code . My issue is when I run on some device image cannot load. When i set image show only blank display.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg>
   <g id="gimg">
      <image id="img" display="none" xlink:href="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" x="0" y="0" height="50px" width="50px"/>
  </g>
  <rect id="myrect" x="100" y="100" width="20" height="20"></rect>
</svg>  
<script>
$("#myrect").on("click",function(){
    $("#img").show();
});
  
</script>
```

Comment: works in pc and not in phones?

Comment: It is not working for me. Does jQuery have access to the shadow dom inside svg elements? I thought it did not.

Comment: Works in FF, Chrome, Edge, IE11

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is in phones try this:

```
$("#myrect").on("click",function(){
   $("#img").show();
   return false;

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you add **style=display: none** to your image element

```
<image id="img" style="display:none" xlink:href="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" x="0" y="0" height="50px" width="50px"/>.
```

This should load the image

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this way?

```
<svg>
<defs>
<symbol id="my-icon" viewBox="0 0 30 30">
  <rect id="myrect" x="25" y="25" width="20" height="20" />
</defs>
</symbol>
<image id="img" display="none" xlink:href="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" x="0" y="0" height="50px" width="50px" />
```

```
</svg>


$("#myrect").on("click", function() {
$("#img").show();
 });
```

Just change the viewBox, etc to your requirements.
I hope this helps.